# Срабатывание анимации при появлении объекта

Tags: jquery, css, анимация

Только начал изучать javascript/jquery. Столкнулся с проблемой. 
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы заголовок h1 при появлении его на экране, плавно выезжал снизу вверх, переходя из прозрачного состояния в непрозрачное.

В плане css все ясно. В исходном состоянии transform: translateY(20px); opacity: 0;
А после того, как элемент попадает в область просмотра, его стили нужно изменить на нужные. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, какое событие нужно обрабатывать и как правильно это написать в jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Для прокрутки страницы событие `window.onscroll`, без jquery примерно так:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var elms = document.querySelectorAll('h1:not(.appear)');
  for (i = 0; i < elms.length; ++i) {
    if (elms[i].offsetTop < scrolled + window.innerHeight - 100) {
      elms[i].classList.add('appear');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100vh 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20vh 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: all .5s;
}

h1.appear {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<h1>StackOverflow</h1>
<h1>Blah Blah</h1>
```

Но для таких событий нужно добавлять дебаунсер, тк событий прилетает очень много.